# print date range in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am newbie in excel. I want macro to take 2 arguments StartDate & EndDate and print Month wise date range like below:

StartDate   EndDate 
01-12-2015  24-08-2016

(Cell A4)   (Cell B4)   (Cell C4)
From            To      Diff In Days
01-12-2015  31-12-2015  31
01-01-2016  31-01-2016  31
01-02-2016  29-02-2016  29
01-03-2016  31-03-2016  31
01-04-2016  30-04-2016  30
01-05-2016  31-05-2016  31
01-06-2016  31-06-2016  31
01-07-2016  30-07-2016  30
01-08-2016  24-08-2016  24

Please help me with the code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need code, you need a formula in column C then you need to fill it up/down your table: `=B10-A10`

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I want to take startdate & enddate from user in Cell A2 & B2 respectively. Macro should populate split them in above mentioned format.

Answer (score 0):

This site isn't a code writing service (people pay for that) but out of my own curiousity I've put this together. Hope it helps.

```
Sub date_info()

Dim date1 As Date
Dim date2 As Date
Dim dateT As Date
Dim myRow As Integer

With ActiveSheet
    .[A3:C1000].ClearContents
    date1 = .[A2].Value
    date2 = .[B2].Value
    myRow = 3
    .Cells(myRow, 1).Value = date1

Do Until dateT > date2
    date1 = DateAdd("m", 1, date1)
    dateT = DateAdd("d", -1, date1)
    .Cells(myRow + 1, 1).Value = date1
    .Cells(myRow, 2).Value = dateT
    .Cells(myRow, 3).Value = .Cells(myRow, 2).Value - .Cells(myRow, 1).Value + 1
    myRow = myRow + 1
Loop

.Cells(myRow, 1).Value = ""
End With
End Sub
```